# How to tell nuget to add package resource files as links, and not copy them into project directory

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

## Intro (how to pack resources into a nuget package)

To pack some resource files into a nuget package, what one would normally do, is the following.

Put all the resource files into the `content\` directory of a nuget package. This would be specified by the following line in a `.nuspec` file:

```
<files>
  <file src="Project\bin\Release\script.js" target="content\js\script.js" />
<files>
```

Now, when this nuget package gets installed into `AnotherProject`, the following file structure emerges:

```
Solution.sln
packages\Project.1.0.0\content\js\script.js  // the original resource file
AnotherProject\js\script.js                  // a physical copy 
AnotherProject\AnotherProject.csproj         // <Content /> tag (see below)
```

During package installation, `AnotherProject.csproj` was injected with tag:

```
<Content Include="js\script.js" />
```

and this is for the physical copy of the original resource (which is under `packages\` directory).

## The actual problem (how to pack resources into a nuget package as link)

My aim is not to have the physical copy of a resource file in the `AnotherProject` directory but rather a "link" to the original resource under `packages\` directory. In the csproj, this should look like this:

```
<Content Include="packages\Project.1.0.0\content\js\script.js">
  <Link>js\script.js</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

## Brute force solution that I would rather avoid

Now, one "do it the hard way" workaround I can think of is:

- not putting resource files under `content\` so they do not get added automatically,
- writing `Install.ps1` script that would hack the csproj file structure and add the necessary XML piece manually,

This, however, has the following drawbacks:

- all my nuget packages need the same script piece in their `Install.ps1`,
- when installing my packages, there would be a nasty "project reload prompt" in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since NuGet currently does not support this out of the box your options are either to use PowerShell or to use a custom MSBuild target.

**PowerShell**

- Leave your resources outside of the Content directory in your NuGet package (as you already suggested).
- Add the file link using PowerShell in the install.ps1.

You should be able to avoid the **project reload prompt** if you use the Visual Studio object model (EnvDTE). I would take a look at Project.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(...) to see if that works for you.

**MSBuild target**

- NuGet supports adding an import statement into a project that points to an MSBuild .props and/or .targets file. So you could put your resources into the **tools** directory of your NuGet package and reference them from a custom MSBuild .props/.targets file.

Typically the custom .props and .targets are used to customise the build process. However they are just MSBuild project files so you could add items for your resources into these project files.

Note that .props are imported at the start of the project file when a NuGet package is installed, whilst .targets are imported at the end of the project.

**Customising NuGet**

Another option, which would take more work, would be to modify NuGet to support what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you! I finally got this to work with powershell using install.ps1 and EnvDTE.
http://www.rhyous.com/2016/03/03/nuget-for-source-using-add-as-link-1/

Comment: Oh, yeah. You can see it in action here: https://github.com/rhyous/SimpleArgs/tree/master/NuGet