# Creating a nuget package, i would like to add a help file(chm) to a folder as a link

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

I am trying to add a sandcastle helpfile (chm ) file to a nuget package, 
but when installed into a project it should be a link to the file not file itself.

The things i have tried so far are.

Modify the csproj file by hand, it works but is the ugly way

```
<None Include="..\folder\path.to\content\HelpFileFolder\myhelpfile.chm">
  <Link>myhelpfile.chm</Link>
</None>
```

I have read in a  number of articles that you can create a init.ps1 file and have powershell take care of this.
[link to stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367541/how-to-tell-nuget-to-add-package-resource-files-as-links-and-not-copy-them-into)

But this doesn`t explain how to do this with Powershell.

Any help would be much appreciated.