# Link files from a NuGet package into a project automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, nuget

I have, what should be, a relatively straight forward issue.  I have an MVC project and I want to share some common views among other MVC projects in the future.

To accomplish this I've create a NuGet package and was hoping to link the common views from the package into the installed project.

NuGet structure:

- /

  - build

    - packageName.props
    - src/

      - test.cshtml

Here is my "packageName.props" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\src\test.cshtml">
      <Link>Views\Shared\test.cshtml</Link>
    </None>   
  </ItemGroup>  
</Project>
```

Unfortunately, this does absolutely nothing.  The only way I can ever get the file to show up is if i add the copy to output element, but it doesn't show as a linked file, it is a copy.  I would really prefer to not go down the powershell route as this should work correctly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

--Just want to clarify that I want to add the files to the projects as links, not copies.--
--I originally got the idea from here [How to tell nuget to add package resource files as links, and not copy them into project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367541/how-to-tell-nuget-to-add-package-resource-files-as-links-and-not-copy-them-into) but they, eventually, go the route of powershell, which I don't want to do.--

Answer (score 1):

From the NuGet Documentation:

> ...you can layout a directory structure that follows the NuGet conventions.
>
> - **tools** - The tools folder of a package is for powershell scripts and programs accessible from the Package Manager Console. After the folder is copied to the target project, it is added to the `$env:Path (PATH) environment variable.
> - **lib** - Assemblies (.dll files) in the lib folder are added as assembly references when the package is installed.
> - **content** - Files in the content folder are copied to the **root of your application** when the package is installed.
> - **build** - The build folder of a package is for MSBuild targets files that are automatically inserted into the .csproj file of the application.
>
> Think of the Content folder as the root of your target application. For example, if I want a package to add an image in the /images directory of the target application, make sure to place the image in the Content/images folder of the package.

The issue is that you are putting content into the build folder (which is meant for `MSBuild` targets only).

```
build/
    packageName.props
content/
    Views/
        Shared/
            test.cshtml
```

I don't believe your `packageName.props` file is required in this case because NuGet will automatically add content files to the Visual Studio project file.

> Do note that deploying content with NuGet isn't a very practical thing to do. If you edit the content after it is installed, NuGet will skip uninstalling it and in the case of upgrading the NuGet package, it will prompt the user to whether or not to overwrite the changes. Since NuGet doesn't have any "merge conflict" feature this is not a very good scenario to be in.
>
> This only works well when you are deploying something like a `jQuery` plugin `.js` file that won't change inside of the project, but may need to be updated to a higher version at some point in the future.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the response.  I actually want the files to be Linked files only, not have them copied directly into the project.  If you put them in the /content folder then they get copied, not linked.

Comment: I see. I am pretty sure that is not supported by NuGet out of the box, since NuGet isn't aware of anything outside of the project folder. That is why every project has an individual `packages.config` file. NuGet might not be the right tool for this task.

Comment: Hmm, I added a related link to the post that makes mention of this via a .props file but the ultimate solution was done with powershell, which i don't want to do

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that works with me for similar cases, is to use `GeneratePathProperty`.
e.g.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="My.Pkg" Version="1.0.0" GeneratePathProperty="true"/> 
  </ItemGroup>
.
.
</Project>
```

Where, `$(PkgMy_Pkg)\Views\Shared\test.cshtml` is the file path, provided that the package `nuspec` file has the following lines:

```
  <files>
    <file src="test.cshtml" target=".\Views\Shared"></file>
  </files>
```